# Moving rows between different UITableViews

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

Suppose I have two lists (represented as two different tableviews) on the same screen, I want to move a row from one tableview to other tableView. Can anybody suggest something for this ?

Update : 
The gesture and corresponding animation should be similar to reordering rows while in edit mode of uitableview.

Comment: You will be using two arrays for each of the Tableviews, just swap the value between arrays for the row you want and then reload both the tables. That's it.

Comment: No dude. I want that gesture and animation.

Comment: then you can use tableview's addRow with animation method on pan gesture response.

Comment: hope you know 

- (void)insertRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation;
- (void)deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation;
- (void)reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation

Comment: Yeah, i know about those methods. But the thing is 'move' means dragging a row from one tableview and drop in another tableview. Those methods will help in deleting and inserting, but not the in between animation of dragging and dropping.